# Xpath failed to locate the child nodes of span

Tags: python, html, xpath

When I tried to locate "span" by using xpath,it works like this.

```
download = new_html.xpath('//*[@id="Zoom"]/span')
print(download)

output:[<Element span at 0x7fa9370bae80>]
```

But when i tried to locate the span's child nodes, it doesn't work.

```
download = new_html.xpath('//*[@id="Zoom"]/span/a/@href')
print(download)

output: []
```

The html structure is like this:

```
<span>
    <img src="xxx" alt="xxx">
    For test.
    <br />
    For test.
    <br />
    <a target="_blank" href="abcabc">click on me.</a>   
</span>
```

Comment: It is an odd mixture of markup, the `img` tag is not closed, the `br` tags are closed in XML syntax as `<br />`. So that begs the question, which parser exactly do you use to parse that input before trying to run XPath against the tree built by the parser?

Comment: This is an example from a real website, which uses this hybrid marking method. So is it possible to match successfully?

Comment: Show us the code parsing the HTML, explain which library you use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lxml as the library to parse the HTML, I can use

```
from lxml import etree as ET

html = '''<div id=zoom>
<span>
    <img src="xxx" alt="xxx">
    For test.
    <br />
    For test.
    <br />
    <a target="_blank" href="abcabc">click on me.</a>   
</span>
</div>
'''

doc = ET.HTML(html)

doc.xpath('//*[@id="zoom"]/span/a/@href')
```

and the result is `['abcabc']`.